# Successful Cloud Function deployment but code not getting reflected. Getting previously executed log

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to update a Cloud Function using Visual Code. Getting successful when I try to update it but the code is not reflecting the update. I tied deleting and updating the function again. It successfully gets deleted and uploaded as well, but still executed previously uploaded Cloud Function.

Getting Firebase Cloud Function logs additionally getting below log as well:

```
    {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"sghadge@xxx.com"},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"115.97.82.202","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"FirebaseCLI/6.0.0,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2019-08-28T06:26:55.075Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","authorizationInfo":[{"permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.update","granted":true,"resourceAttributes":{}},{"resource":"projects/sample-project/locations/us-central1/functions/updateProduct","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.update","granted":true,"resourceAttributes":{}}],"resourceName":"projects/sample-project/locations/us-central1/functions/updateProduct","request":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.UpdateFunctionRequest","function":{"name":"projects/wardrobe-manager-dev/locations/us-central1/functions/updateProduct","httpsTrigger":{},"labels":{"deployment-callable":"true","deployment-tool":"cli-firebase"},"sourceUploadUrl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-7dced446-cee5-4518-a082-90e14aaed2ce/db6dbd9d-5c89-4804-b83a-f04a2ee2d929.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-42911962822@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1566975412&Signature=dAr1G%2BGKr79OUOotyYLlqX1uFL2ua1%2F22EF6HabVLFrlrgXQRGc6ZRKqLITM1JjlATSVyRUQH4SvPsDaVC8zd7yQSGFBzJqlbO3tBLpW01VPZSbrCLbYlvRHQ7F9VK%2F%2Fw7S8Q%2FQ83tEh0jluRPkMpwChH%2BdhrxndthToJSx0EIYFs2FlPahYuwrnDmxeQVxeWza2LIRXBJ%2BW%2BlDEZLTfGwcaVqKj51nwhcHXAynK7g2GenTHxw1qUW4ZsO6CiqhnRoly%2F6z2BCcF8iqFdwAlOvWa9dkeXSMrxVG9L6c3COA3IF3Up50Ojv5lgZY8PTpJ6vwDsrHwKduRJXhWij8cKw%3D%3D"},"updateMask":"sourceUploadUrl,name,labels,httpsTrigger"}}
```

```
{
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "authenticationInfo": {
        "principalEmail": "sghadge@xxx.com"
    },
    "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
    "resourceName": "projects/sample-project/locations/us-central1/functions/updateProduct",
    "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "status": {}
}
```

Any Suggestion kindly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support directly if you're unable to deploy functions.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: yes raised issue..